# Retrieving missing entries from a file

Tags: c, arrays, nested-loops

Say there's a text file 'measurements' that looks like this:

```
         London     1   0.5
         London     2   1.0
          Tokyo     3   2.0
         London     6  18.4
          Tokyo    11  -1.0
          Tokyo     1  -0.3
        Toronto     3  -1.0
         London     8   8.0
        Toronto    11  11.0
        Toronto    12  10.4
         London     7  -5.6
```

Where the first column stores the cities' names, the second one represents the month in which the measurement took place, and the third one is simply the average temperature for that month in the given city. Now, what I want is to read all this data, and find for what months there are no entries for one city(e.g. London 3, Tokyo 6 etc.), and put all of that in the text file called 'errors'.
Here's how I tried, but ultimately got stuck:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct City {
    char name[20];
    int month;
    float avg;

};

int scan(struct City *arr, int len)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("measurements.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error while reading.");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i = 0;
    while ((fscanf(fp,"%12s%d%f\n", arr[i].name, &arr[i].month, &arr[i].avg)) == 3)
        i++;
    fclose(fp);
    return i;
}

void sort(struct City *arr, int len)
{
    struct City temp[100];
    int         i, j;

    for (i = 0 ; i < len - 1 ; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1 ; j < len; j++) {
            int compare = strcmp(arr[i].name, arr[j].name);
            if (compare > 0) {
                temp[i] = arr[i];
                arr[i]  = arr[j];
                arr[j]  = temp[i];
            }
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    struct City array[100];
    int len = scan(array,1000);
    sort(array, len);

    FILE *fout;

    fout = fopen("missing.txt","w");
    if (fout == NULL) {
        printf("Error while printing");
        exit(1);
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 1 ; i < len ; i++) {
        int j, m = 1, found = 0;
        for (j = 1 ; j <= 12 ; j++) {
            while (strcmp(array[m - 1].name, array[m].name) == 0) {
                if (array[m - 1].month == j)
                    found=1;
            }
            if (found == 0)
                fprintf(fout,"%15s %d",array[i].name, j);
        }
    }
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I run this program, the file 'output' remains empty, which I guess, is due to a mistake in the nested loops near the end of the code. I feel there must be a simpler and more elegant way to do this. How would you approach this problem?

Comment: Why aren't you using SQL?

Comment: why did you reedit the code? did you add something? also use more whitespace to make your code clear and easy to read, the compiler will ignore them anyway.

Comment: No I just corrected grammar mistakes. Thanks for the edit of yours.

Comment: beware, you're trying to access outside the array : array[m - 1] when m==0. that's maybe why you can't find a match.

Comment: Good catch. That doesn't seem to solve the problem though, it juts prints the all of the months.

Comment: What would be a more elegant way, without those loops? Maybe the use of a function to compare integer arrays?

Comment: @Shema did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can build an array of months which would have an integer value indicating if the month is present, then for each citi name, you iterate until the city name changes in a while loop, making each entry in the array equal to `1` for each entry in the file, after the array will contain in the **missing** months positions - 1, a `0` so if it does you output that value to the file.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct City {
    char name[20];
    int month;
    float avg;

};

int scan(struct City *arr, int len)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("measurements.txt", "r");
    int   i  = 0;

    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error while reading.");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((fscanf(fp,"%12s%d%f\n", arr[i].name, &arr[i].month, &arr[i].avg)) == 3)
        i++;
    fclose(fp);

    return i;

}

void sort(struct City *arr, int len)
{
    struct City temp[100];
    int         i, j;

    for (i = 0 ; i < len - 1 ; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1 ; j < len; j++) {
            int compare = strcmp(arr[i].name, arr[j].name);
            if(compare > 0) {
                temp[i] = arr[i];
                arr[i]  = arr[j];
                arr[j]  = temp[i];
            }
        }
    }

}

int main()
{
    struct City array[100];
    FILE       *fout;
    int         len;
    const char *previous;
    int         month;

    len = scan(array, 100);
    if (len == 0)
        return -1;
    sort(array, len);

    fout = fopen("missing.txt","w");
    if (fout == NULL) {
        printf("Error while printing");
        return -1;
    }
    previous = NULL;
    month    = 1;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
        int months[12] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

        previous = array[i].name;
        while (strcmp(previous, array[i].name) == 0)
        {
            int month;
            month = array[i].month;
            if ((month >= 0) && (month < 12))
                months[month - 1] = 1;
            i += 1;
        }
        i -= 1;

        for (int j = 0 ; j < 12 ; j++)
        {
            if (months[j] != 0)
                continue;
            fprintf(fout, "%15s%5d\n", previous, j + 1);
        }
    }
    fclose(fout);

    return 0;
}
```